# Decide if user has made a lap of a track in Swift Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I have a track with walls made of sprite nodes, and a ball that is a sprite node, who am I able to set a start point within the track walls and also detect if the ball has gone around the track and made a 'lap'.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at uibezierpath on the apple dev website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to determine if a ball has made a lap is to add two sprites that span the width the track as shown the figure below. You then need to keep track of the order in which the ball touches the green and red sprites. If the ball touches the green and then the red in a reasonable amount of time, increment a lap counter. If the ball touches the red and then the green decrement the counter. If the count is positive, the ball has made a lap.

[image]